# How to compile phantomJs on a machine and then 'port' it on a other?

Tags: linux

I've a Ubuntu 15.04 VPS with only 512MB of RAM. It's enough. No Problem.

But I need to compile ("build") phantomJs, because there is no linux packages available. This require as much as 4GB of RAM, but for only the limited, compile-time, period.

I'm asking you if I can build it on a VM on my pc, and then 'migrate' it on the VPS. I know that under Windows you cannot 'move' or 'copy' an already installed software, but, is it possible under Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. As long as you've moved everything that's needed, including dependancies, you should be fine.

A better idea would be to build it as a proper package, or do a quick and dirty package with [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) and install that with dpkg.

Comment: +1 for suggestion of checkinstall. Anyway this is not the answer to my spceific situation. This software cannot be installed. It has only a `.build.sh` command that create A TON of binaries. I'm not able to intercept this file creation with checkinstall.